# Sitecore Powershell: Find users last login?

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I'm writing a very simple Sitecore PowerShell script to report on all users in our system. We'd like to know the last login date for each user, but I've had no luck getting at it. I can access $_.Profile.LastActivityDate, but that doesn't help as it appears it's the same value for all users. Any ideas what the expression is to access the last login date, or how I can find it? Thanks.

```
Get-User -Filter * |

Show-ListView -Property @{Label="User"; Expression={ $_.Profile.UserName} },
    @{Label="Full Name"; Expression={ $_.Profile.FullName} },
    @{Label="Email"; Expression={ $_.Profile.Email} },
    @{Label="Logged In"; Expression={ $_.Profile.LastActivityDate } }

Close-Window
```

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657780/get-user-created-date-in-sitecore (it's talking about the created date, but it looks like two people are taking a different approach to yours to get user info)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Get-User`](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Get-User.html) will output one or more `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User`, whose `Profile` property is a `Sitecore.Security.UserProfile` which inherits from `System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase`. So, the `LastActivityDate` property should be the same as you'd get by accessing the profile outside of Sitecore.

That said, there is a chance that simply accessing the profile data will update the last activity date.

> The LastActivityDate for a user is updated by the classes in the
>   System.Web.Profile and the System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
>   namespaces **whenever user data is retrieved from** or set at the data
>   source. ...

So, you may be able to avoid accessing the profile, and instead, retrieve MembershipUsers. `MembershipUser` has a property named `LastLoginDate` which I think is what you're after:

```
[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GetAllUsers() |

Show-ListView -Property @{Label="User"; Expression={ $_.UserName} },
    @{Label="Is Online"; Expression={ $_.IsOnline} },
    @{Label="Creation Date"; Expression={ $_.CreationDate} },
    @{Label="Last Login Date"; Expression={ $_.LastLoginDate} },
    @{Label="Last Activity Date"; Expression={ $_.LastActivityDate } }
```

If you need access to the profile without updating the last activity date, you might also try:

```
[System.Web.Security.Membership]::GetUser("sitecore\admin", $false)
```

Comment: I believe you're right that accessing profile does update LastActivityDate. This is a great solution for accessing the login date, and will help us greatly with account maintenance. Thanks!